# Website slow loading on VPS

Tags: mysql, performance, apache, nginx, centos

I have VPS, CentOS 6 64bit with directadmin + custombuild.

Web server: Apache with reverse proxy by Nginx.

I am hosting a lot of websites on this VPS.
when there are a lot of hits on website "example.com", that website becoming extremely slow (can be 50 seconds and more), but the others work perfect and fast.

I checked CPU and Memory, but there are nothing weird.

I installed "mytop" for monitoring database, and it happened when there are 20+- running queries.

my.cnf content:

```
[mysqld] 
max_allowed_packet=16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5096M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 12
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 10M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup = 1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8
innodb_thread_concurrency = 12
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT 
innodb_read_io_threads = 4
innodb_write_io_threads = 8 
#max_connections = 800
#max_user_connections = 400
local-infile=0


max_connections=120 #
interactive_timeout=300
join_buffer_size=512K
key_buffer_size=64M
query_cache_limit=4G
tmp_table_size=1024M
max_heap_table_size=512M #
thread_cache_size=4
open_files_limit=50000
table_open_cache=3000

query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=128M #
```

I dont know if its mysql problem or apache and nginx problem.

Comment: 20 running queries?  Let's see some of them.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant table(s).

Answer (score 0):

The information you give is pretty sparse. You should probably check the general cpu usage and see what applications use the cpu. However if the other applications on the server are still performing well then you probably have some slow database queries. 20+ sounds pretty much depending on what you call lots of hits. You should probably analyse which database queries are running and how long they take. Maybe you need to add indexes.
Another problem could be locks in the database.

Comment: There is no cpu or memory problem. Like I said, The problem is happened when there are 20 hits at same second, but it not for sure.

Comment: You should also check for database locks.